# Why is this model not updating?

Tags: entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on a project with movie information index. In this application when the manager updates a movie poster with referencing MovieID, it successfully updates the movie with filename of the uploaded jpeg image with extension as PosterSrc.

I used db.SaveChanges() to save the context after done editing the new values.

```
<img src="/UploadedFiles/Posters/@Model.PosterSrc" alt="@Model.Title" />
```

But in a different view, it does not render the updated image because it loads old value for the field of PosterSrc.

After updating value I made sure to check by both debugging and checking the updated value using a SQL query and could see it only updates database but not dbContext? What should I do?

Edit: It loads the updated field if I ran the application again.

Comment: How are you instantiating/disposing your context?

Comment: For each repository I instantiate a type of context as db and I use it as the context.   private readonly ShopEntities db = new ShopEntities();

Comment: You need to either wrap your statements inside a `using { ... }` block or use IoC where it disposes the context per request: https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/03/27/managing-entity-framework-dbcontext-lifetime-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx